# apache virtualhost to be limited to one domain on the same server

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost

I have several domains running under apache. Most of theme they do not have yet virtualhost. My problem is that all this not registered domains by apache are getting redireted to the setup domain. How to force apache to accept request just from the domain.

what I mean

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin info@mydomain.com
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias mydomain.com www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

than I have for example `domain1.co.uk, domain2.org`
all are redirected to `mydomain.com`. This should be avoided

if I use wildcar like ServerAlias *.domain1.co.uk and I have subdomain svn.domain1.co.uk than the svn subdomain is going to be redirected to domain1.co.uk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a *default* virtualhost, like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add your domain names in the `ServerAlias` directive's list an configure each DNS zone to resolve as your Web server.

Comment: and what about if I have for example for mydomain.org a subdomain (test.mydomain.org) in this case the wildcard (.*) won't work

Comment: In `ServerAlias`, you can specify `*.mydomain.org` if this is what you mean.